# Display related values of picklist on next page in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, picklist

I am working on Lightning Experience POC. I need to display picklist field and when i select Option A then its related values like a1, a2 should display on next page. Will you please help in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have created picklist component in lighning but next i ma not able to understand how to display selected value on next page.

Comment: You need something like dependent picklists, but usually they should be displayed in same page.

Comment: Can we display selected values on next field? in text?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, would be better if you can elaborate it clearly.

Comment: Actually i want to display selected value of picklist on next page in text. Previously i wanted to display related values but as you suggested dependent picklist will work. Now want to display just selected picklist value. I hope i make it understand.